# Error with ajax request POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have some problems with request to file. 
I have to edit the data in the table created in the plugin. When I click on the text, I create an input. I change the data and when I press the enter key this data should be sent to the update_cell.php file but when I output it for `example echo $ _POST ["id "]` I get the error Notice:

> Undefined index: id in W: \ domains \ test \ wp-content \ plugins \
>   related-equipment \ includes \ update_cell.php on line 2

Is it possible my path is incorrectly specified? Although I propps it as absolute. I think problems should not be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('td.edit').click(function(){
$('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
$('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
$(this).addClass('ajax');
$(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="'+ $(this).text().length+'" type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '" />');
$('#editbox').focus();
});

//UPDATE TABLE
$('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
eq_arr = $(this).attr('class').split( " " );
   if(event.which == 13)
   {
var table = $('table').attr('id');
 $.ajax({ type: "POST",
 url:"http://test/wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update_cell.php",
 data: "value="+jQuery('.ajax input').val()+"&id="+eq_arr[1]+"&field="+eq_arr[2]+"&table=gc-equip",
 success: function(data){
     console.log(this);
 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
 $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
 }});
 }});

 $(document).on('blur', '#editbox', function(){
$('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
$('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
});
});
```

Comment: unlikely to be the path, but could be badly encoded data. Pass the data as an object (e.g. `data: { "value:" jQuery('.ajax input').val(), "id": eq_arr[1]` ...etc. Then jQuery will serialise encode it correctly for transmission in the request with no possibility of problems due to special characters in the input etc. Concatenating your own data like that is verbose and asking for trouble. Also check that `eq_arr[1]` actually has a value at the time of posting, and use your browser's network tools to examine the request and see what variables were actually sent in the body

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data like this with post method :

```
data : {
    value: jQuery('.ajax input').val(),
    id: eq_arr[1],
    field: eq_arr[2]
    // and so on
}
```

Then after you can get the values at server side using `$_POST[key]`  here `key` will be `value`, `id`, `field` that you passed via `ajax`

Comment: value it's a key?

Comment: Yes, if you want `value` then you can get by using `$_POST['value']` and for get `id`, get with `$_POST['id']`

Comment: in console after click enter output this string {url: "http://test/wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update_cell.php", type: "POST", isLocal: false, global: true, processData: true, …}

Comment: $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
 url:"http://test/wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update_cell.php",
 data: ({value: jQuery('.ajax input').val(),
    id: eq_arr[1],
    field: eq_arr[2],
    url: eq_arr[3]
 }),
 success: function(data){
     console.log(eq_arr);
 $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
 $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
 }});
 }}); Did as suggested in the comments above, the error remained the same

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id

Comment: Check the post parameters which sent to server using ajax. You can find it in console. Are they sent properly with values ??

Comment: Can an error because of that that from the table the data at me are deduced as object?

Comment: `<?php foreach($edit_eq as $eq_arr):
        echo '
     <tr>
<td class="edit title '.$eq_arr->id.'">'.$eq_arr->title.'</td>
<td class="edit anonce '.$eq_arr->id.'">'. $eq_arr->anonce.'</td>
<td class="edit url '.$eq_arr->id.'">'.$eq_arr->url.'</td>
<td class="edit category '.$eq_arr->id.'\">'.$eq_arr->relcat.'</td>
</tr>';
endforeach ?>`